# AWS policy statement returning no conditions when explicit conditions are set

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I created a policy out of a policy document json and I'm trying to get the condition_entries from each statement. In the following example I only have one statement and one condition, but for some reasons I'm getting an empty list returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
from policyuniverse.policy import Policy
def test_conditions_entries(self):
    policy_document = {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Action': 'iam:DeleteUser',
            'Resource': '*',
            'Condition': {'StringLike': {'iam:ResourceTag/status': 'terminated'}}
        }]
    }
    p = Policy(policy_document)
    for statement in p.statements:
        print(statement.statement)
        print(statement.condition_entries)


{'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': 'iam:DeleteUser', 'Resource': '*', 'Condition': {'StringLike': {'iam:ResourceTag/status': 'terminated'}}}
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `iam:ResourceTag/status` is not working.

The following does not work:

```
{"StringLike": {"iam:ResourceTag/status": "terminated"}
```

The following does work.

```
Condition = {
    'StringLike': {
        'AWS:SourceOwner': '012345678910'
    }
}
```

hope this help you some extend.

Comment: I think the resource tags inside IAM role are new concepts right and may be not yet supported. its just my guess

Comment: You can see the supported conditions here: https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/policyuniverse/blob/master/policyuniverse/statement.py. It only supports a handful of condition keys and all of them begin "aws:". So, the statement constructor is silently ignoring the "iam:ResourceTag/status" condition completely. Not ideal behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I tested a few other Conditions and those worked. I suppose this is still not supported yet.